# How to insert image into MS Visio using xml

Tags: xml, visio

I need to insert an image in Ms Visio document, but this option must work even if Visio isn't install on PC.So i decided to work with xml and save it as vdx.I know that image should contain in ForeignData tags, but don't understand how to convert image in format like xkFloTPcR/u+6YH7S4RTnA8SPOq5CdH0uxmCXFqnvqpW1i3Hx8QAPxqLX7udtMlhu5WmbC7Wc5JGR

Answer (score 0):

"xkFloTPcR/u+6YH7S4RTnA8SPOq5CdH0uxmCXFqnvqpW1i3Hx8QAPxqLX7udtMlhu5WmbC7Wc5JGR..." is simply [base64-encoded](https://www.google.com/search?q=base64) image (binary data). It is a standard way to represent binary data (such as image) as text (e.g. in xml or html).

How to encode image binary into base64 depends on the language/framework you use, but all major ones have this functionality either built-in or as a library function.